# Advice on using geolocation to determine which page to display

Tags: php, html, geolocation

I was looking for a little friendly advice on a project I'm working on.  It is built using PHP and HTML5.

I am working on an eCommerce site for stores that are located in Texas.  The company is thinking about offering different a different pricing structure to customers within Texas as opposed to those outside of Texas.

The way I have come up to do this is to use geolocation to get the users location and check it against the geographical center of Texas.  If the distance is less than 450 miles show one page, or, if the distance is greater, show another.  I know this would not be the exact border of the state, and I think that is OK.

The only problem I have come up with this idea so far is that a user could deny the location check.  How does it work on Google when you type in restaurants in the search and it gives you local places without asking for permission?

Do you guys have any other suggestions?  In the searching I have done, I haven't found any other ideas that seem to fit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

People who wish to do this generally use a GeoIP library which can tell you where the users IP is coming from.  Note that this does not tell you where the user is physically.  You can opt to use one of these too however you must know that anyone could be from TX if they were using a proxy based in TX.  You would have to have some strict checking on orders to make sure that people were not spoofing their location with a proxy and placing orders that would be shipped outside of TX.

What would happen if your customer resided inside TX borders but for some reason their ISP was routing them through a router in Oklahoma or New Mexico.  To your GeoIP it would look like they are from out of state.

The best solution (but not the best user experience) would be to ask a potential customer for their location.  If they provide a location use that, if they don't fall back to the GeoIP.  Always update the pricing for the product during checkout if you detect they are from out of state but provide an in-state address.  Chances are they are from TX but the GeoIP does not think they are.

MaxMind - http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing
These guys offer both a free and paid solution.  I have used both and can tell you that the paid solution is well worth the cost vs the inaccuracies you will get when using the free version.